# IniFiles use array or hash

Tags: perl, file, hash, ini

I have to transpose a PHP script to Perl.

In my PHP script I parse an ini file with array elements in it as for example...

```
[RADIUS]
SRV[] = "server 1"
SRV[] = "server 2"
SRV[] = "server 3"
...
SRV[] = "server n"
```

This works fine in PHP, and my question is, can I use the same ini file in Perl or must I rewrite this as following

```
[RADIUS]
SRV1 = "server 1"
SRV2 = "server 2"
SRV3 = "server 3"
...
SRV4 = "server n"
```

This is not clear in CPAN.

For the first variant I can walk through the hash and read my values with a while loop, or so and I do not have to take care if I remove an item that the numbering is consistent.

Any hint is welcome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which module from CPAN are you using to do that?

Comment: Config::IniFiles
http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.94/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm

Comment: Please [edit] and show the code you have written and what you want to do with your config. Is it important if those server things end up in an array? Do you need them to be in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I made work for me using the Config:IniFiles:

```
use Config::IniFiles;
# Read Ini File
my %MyCfg;
tie %MyCfg, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => "..".$MyPathSep."ini".$MyPathSep."file.ini" );
foreach my $List1 (sort keys %{$MyCfg{'DataCenters'}}) {
    if (ref $MyCfg{'DataCenters'}{$List1} eq 'ARRAY') {
        foreach my $List2 (sort keys @{$MyCfg{'DataCenters'}{$List1}}) {
            print $MyCfg{'DataCenters'}{$List1}[$List2]."\n";
        }
    } else {
        print $MyCfg{'DataCenters'}{$List1}."\n";
    }
}
```

For the Input section:

```
[DataCenters]
; DC in location a
LOCa[] = "DC1"
LOCa[] = "DC2"
LOCa[] = "DC3"
LOCa[] = "DC4"
; DC in location b
LOCb[] = "DC5"
```

The output is:

```
 scripts\bin>perl switchcfg.pl
    "DC1"
    "DC2"
    "DC3"
    "DC4"
    "DC5"
```

Thank you for your contribution!
Regards
Laurent

Answer (score 2):

You can use the your ini-file directly, but with some twists.

According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles):

> **val ($section, $parameter [, $default] )**
>
> Returns the value of the specified parameter ($parameter) in section
>   $section, returns undef (or $default if specified) if no section or no
>   parameter for the given section exists.
>
> If you want a multi-line/value field returned as an array, just
>   specify an array as the receiver:
>
> ```
> @values = $cfg->val('Section', 'Parameter');
> ```
>
> A multi-line/value
>   field that is returned in a scalar context will be joined using $/
>   (input record separator, default is \n) if defined, otherwise the
>   values will be joined using \n.

The following:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Config::IniFiles;

use Data::Dumper;

my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "./conf.ini" );
my @v = $cfg->val( 'RADIUS', 'SRV[]' );
say Dumper \@v;
```

produces a 4 element array,

```
$VAR1 = [
          '"server 1"',
          '"server 2"',
          '"server 3"',
          '"server n"'
        ];
```

Also note:

- the usage of the `SRV[]` for the parameter name.
- and the returned array elements contains the `"` quote characters.

Comment: Could the downvoter comment how I could improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

One could also read file line by line and store desired values, if you are familiar with a little bit of regex. I use this in my example below.

If you don't need a particular order of "server 1", "server 2".. values, then you may use Hash, otherwise, go for an array.

Here, from your example, a sample test file:

```
%_Host@User> cat srv.txt
SRV[] = "server 1"
SRV[] = "server 2"
SRV[] = "server 3"
SRV[] = "server 109"
SRV[] = "server 51"
%_Host@User>
```

I read it by catting the file to the script and then I generate a Hash and an Array, as seen the Data::Dumper output below.

```
%_Host@User> cat srv.txt |perl test.pl

# Hash output [unordered]
$VAR1 = '"server 109"';
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = '"server 51"';
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = '"server 1"';
$VAR6 = 1;
$VAR7 = '"server 3"';
$VAR8 = 1;
$VAR9 = '"server 2"';
$VAR10 = 1;

# Array output [in order]
$VAR1 = '"server 1"';
$VAR2 = '"server 2"';
$VAR3 = '"server 3"';
$VAR4 = '"server 109"';
$VAR5 = '"server 51"';
%_Host@User>
```

Now you got both options, and you may proceed as you wish.

**Here is the script:** Its logic is: if line matches 'server' then process and extract values and store in hash and array, else skip.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper ;
my %hash ;
my @array ;

while (<>)
{
  if (m/server/) {
    if (m/^.+? = (.+)$/) {
      $hash{$1} = 1 ;
      push (@array, $1) ;
    }
  }
}

print Dumper %hash ;
print Dumper @array ;
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel if there are already several modules to do this?

Comment: @simbabque: for originality. :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. CPAN modules usually have test suites for automated tests and mostly can handle special cases. You could reinvent the wheel for yourself, but please do not use it as answers here when there are CPAN modules.